# Debian Static route does not work (/etc/network/interfaces)

Tags: networking, debian, route

This is the content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens18
iface ens18 inet static
        address 10.0.5.108
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        gateway 10.0.4.1
        post-up route add -net 10.0.12.0/24 gw 10.0.4.1
        pre-down route del -net 10.0.12.0/24 gw 10.0.4.1
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong? Using the command `ip route add 10.0.12.0/24 via 10.0.4.1` works fine...

`ip r` gives this after a reboot:

```
root@server:~# ip r
default via 10.0.4.1 dev ens18 onlink 
10.0.4.0/22 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.5.108
10.64.0.1 dev tun0 proto static 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you have installed 'route' binary, looks like it doesn't installed. What's about `which route`?

Comment: Holy shit, you are right. Its not installed, and using ```apt install net-tools``` and a reboot fixed everything... Not thought this could be a problem if the ip route add command works.... (Its a debian netinstall)

Comment: Don't use the `route` command. It's depreceated. Update your pre-up to `ip route add ...`

Comment: Use `ifup -v <iface>` command to troubleshoot interface configuration issues.